# Trouble importing partials into a Leaf template

Tags: vapor, leaf

I am creating a single page web app, but for development I am writing it in sections. I want Leaf to serve up a base file which then includes the separate sections pulled from the different partial leaf template files.

I can use #get in a base template and #set in the include but I can only get this to work as a one on one link. I've seen there is a to import but I can't seem to get it to work.
This is the code I currently have in my routes.swift

```
router.get("/test") { req -> Future<View> in
    let leaf = try req.make(LeafRenderer.self)
    let context = "Some data"
    return leaf.render("test", context)
}
```

This is the code I have in my base.leaf file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

#get(test)

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code I have in the test.leaf file.

```
#set('test'){
<h1> Hello there</h1>
}
#embed('base')
```

I thought I could use multiple #get commands but that does not seem to work as the route has to specify the partial for it to work (I think).

For example, I want to embed 3 child pages into one base template.
In the base template I have the following code inside the  tag.

```
#get(section1)
#get(section2)
#get(section3)
```

And I have three corresponding leaf templates for each section. How to I make sure that all sections get injected?

Comment: That should work as you have it (assuming single quote strings `'` are supported, I'm not 100% sure about that). Check out the [new Leaf docs](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/leaf/overview/#embedding-templates) if you haven't already. There's a section on embedding templates there.

Comment: What if I want to import more than one section into a template page. So I can have a template with a nav bar & footer but then have a number of sections written as individual sections to compartmentalise the functionality. The code. Above works for one page but I cannot seem to embed more than one section in the template